# Is it possible to solve the difference equation $K_{n+1}=aK_n+bK_n^{\theta}+c$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is it possible to solve the difference equation $K_{n+1}=aK_n+bK_n^{\theta}+c$, where a, b, c are real numbers while $\theta\in (0,1)$?  How about $\theta=\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $\theta = 2$ you have the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), for which there is a closed form solution only in a few special cases.  With general $\theta$, I would think it is even more unlikely that you would have closed form solutions.